# Issue Injecting a Local EJB on a JSF 2.0 ManagedBean, WLS 10.3.6

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, ejb-3.1, weblogic11g

I'm trying a very simple task of injecting an EJB on a JSF ManagedBean, both web and ejb module are in the same ear, I'm using a local interface of a stateless ejb, however, when trying to render the view which references the managed bean, I get this error:

```
GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/ejecutivo.xhtml]
javax.ejb.EJBException: Attempt to pass a reference to an EJBLocalObject to a remote client. A local EJB component may only be accessed by clients co-located in the same ear or standalone jar file.
    at cl.bbb.vrc.ejb.bean.NotaClienteEJB_eeud7i_NotaClienteServiceImpl.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
[...]
```

My project setup is this:

[image]

And I'm using Weblogic 10.3.6 (From OEPE) and JSF 2.0 shared library from WLS

I have tried every posible combination of dependency settings on the proyects on eclipse, but I can't get it to work, even exported an EAR and made sure that the war and ejb-jar were on it, deployed it on WLS, but got the same error.

If I change to @Remote Interface, I get a **NotSerializableException**

I already googled all over but didn't get anything useful for this issue...

**EDIT**
Okay, it has something to do with managedbean's serialization for client state saving method, I changed it to server and it works fine, however, I need to know why is this behavior happening. Maybe is a WLS 10.3.6 issue or setting?

Comment: Have you considered opening a service request at My Oracle Support?